# How to configure environment variables in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I configured the environment variables `$JAVA_HOME` and `$M2_HOME` the etc/environment file through the root, as follows:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​:
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/:
CLASSPATH:PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:PATH:
$M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven/:
M2=$M2_HOME/bin:
PATH=$M2:$PATH"
```

broken lines for ease of viewing.

After restart the computer and type the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `echo "$JAVA_HOME"` displays nothing.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You might be better off asking on [askbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: All your variables are faulty. `$M2_HOME=...` should be `M2_HOME=...`; your `XXX_HOME` should not end with `:`, you have for some reason a `"` after `PATH` and at the last line. Shortly, your structure is completely wrong.

Comment: Hello Olivier Grégoire that was another doubt, what is the correct way to use the environment variables and where to put them?

Comment: Olivier Grégoire is now correct? I insert them at the end of .bashrc file? `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​`
`CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/‌​CLASSPATH`
`PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:PATH`

`M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven/`
`M2=$M2_HOME/bin`
`PA‌​TH=$M2:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment

Also it is not clear why do you have colons at the end of each line. PATH seems to have unclosed quote.

Maybe you should post the original file without line breaks?

Comment: So the correct would put my ambinte variables at the end of my .bashrc file?

Comment: Dmitry Lukashin used the colon as a separator `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​:CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/:CLASSPATH:PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:PATH:$M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven/:M2=$M2_HOME/bin:PATH=$M2:$PATH"`